# Magento2 Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Address

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, invoice

I am placing an order which consists of 2 items out of which one product is Giftcard and the other one is a Simple product.
I place the order with these items using the Hyperpay Payment method which is a third party. 
The order get's placed successfully.

My issue is when I try to create the invoice of this order with both the items I face the
 **`Type Error issue`** saying:

```
"Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Address".
```

Also, the order status becomes complete. I tried debugging this issue but had no luck

[image].

Comment: got same error in magento 2.3.2. any luck ?

Comment: My case : i am facing same issue in backend order  simple product + virtual product with  address but post code and region are empty.

Comment: it looks like it has been fixed in Magento 2.3.4: https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2362

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Any solution for this Error ?